# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'type' in undefined - Google Earth Engine - GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, error

I want to create a `ui.Select()` to show the centroid for a polygon.

My code

```js
var places = { g1: Geometry_1, g2: Geometry_2}

var select_button = ui.Select({
    item: Object.keys(places),
    onChange: function(key){
      var geometry = places.key
      var centroid = geometry.centroid()
      ui.Panel.add(centroid)
    }
})
```

but when I use the 'key' to return a polygon from the list of polygons it returns "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'type' in undefined". It´s crazy, because if I write the key manually, like 'places.g1', it returns exactly what I need.

Comment: I guess that IN in the error message means that your code forwards a list and that is not supported. Like in SQL "select * from table where attribute in (value1, value2)". Do you have only "places.g1" as input in your test?

Comment: Try replacing `places.key` with `places[key]`. The former will look for a key *called* "key" instead of the variable stored in `key` and return `undefined`.

Comment: I can´t know how it works, but the solution was use `ee.Dictionary(places).get(key)` to get the Geometry from the array. GEE have a lot of bugs... A lot of types to have the same operation.. If one don't work you need try the others. I spend more time finding the form to manipulate data than writing the code...

Comment: @AaronZuspan I think your solution could work. I was very confused why a variable that return a key value can´t use to set array position key. I just tried `places.get(key)` and it doesn't work too. I´m beginner java developer, and most beginner GEE developer. With each project I'm understanding particularities, like `ee.Array()` vs `ee.List()` manipulation data.

Answer (score 1):

`places.key` is the same thing as `places['key']`, which looks up the string value `'key'`, which doesn't exist. Like Aaron said, you have to  `places[key]` to use the variable.

A couple of other issues:

- It's `items`, not `item`
- You cannot `ui.Panel.add(centroid)`. You need an instance of `ui.Panel` and add to that. Still, you cannot add an `ee.Geometry` to a panel. Maybe you wanted to add it as a layer on the map?

Here's your script with some tweaks - hopefully this can help you a bit on the way.

```
var Geometry_1 = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 10])
var Geometry_2 = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 20])
var places = {g1: Geometry_1, g2: Geometry_2}

var select_button = ui.Select({
    items: Object.keys(places),
    onChange: function(key){
      var geometry = places[key]
      var centroid = geometry.centroid()
      print(centroid)
      Map.addLayer(centroid)
    }
})

Map.add(select_button)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/51cb46e39ce6c5fb6f6e5bcc1aa7d95f